# child height:100% troubles

Tags: html, css

I am having child height issues with `div.wrapper .content ul.feeder`. Hopefully you guys can see whats wrong...

Heres a snippet of my code:

```
html, body {height:100%;background:#F7F7F7;}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#333;
}
* .left {float:left;}
* .right {float:right;}
* .center  {margin:auto auto;}
* a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    font-weight:inherit;
}

div.wrapper .content {
    width:calc(100% - 202px);
    min-height:calc(100% - 85px);
    margin:10px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #DCDCDC;
}
div.wrapper .content ul.feeder {
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    border-right:1px solid rgba(53,53,53,0.2);
    list-style-type:none;   
}
div.wrapper .content ul.feeder li.title {
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight:300;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(53,53,53,0.2);
}
div.wrapper .content ul.feeder li.item {
    padding:10px;
}
div.wrapper .content ul.feeder li.item:hover {
    background:#F7F7F7;
}
```

When attempting to use this code, my `div.wrapper .content ul.feeder` **doesn't** get it's height set to 100%, Why might this be?

edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V76yx/)

edit: [working example with jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xazijaqu/1/edit)

Comment: post the markup too please, Also I suggest making a http://jsfiddle.net showing the problem

Comment: We need a *complete* code example. Add your HTML and a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: In order for an element to inherit its parent height, each of its ancestors need to have its height explicitly defined. We can't help you without seeing all relevant markup but I see `.content` does not have an explicit height

Comment: @andrew > update - http://jsfiddle.net/V76yx/

Comment: div.wrapper doesn't have it's height set. So its children can not get a percentage height based on it.

Comment: @KyleShevlin - but `calc()` outputs as a pixel amount? (I also tried the same code on jsbin.com and it worked as intended > http://jsbin.com/xazijaqu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

@koala_dev  is correct;

```
 div.wrapper .content
```

needs

```
height:100%
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMYZB/)**

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by doing `min-height:calc(100% - 85px);` to `height:calc(100% - 85px);` for `div.wrapper .content`:

```
div.wrapper .content {
    width:calc(100% - 202px);
    height:calc(100% - 85px);
    margin:10px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #DCDCDC;
}
    div.wrapper .content ul.feeder {
        width:500px;
        height:100%;
        overflow:auto;
        border-right:1px solid rgba(53,53,53,0.2);
        list-style-type:none;   
    }
    div.wrapper .content ul.feeder li.title {
        font-size:32px;
        font-weight:300;
        padding:10px;
        border-bottom:1px solid rgba(53,53,53,0.2);
    }
    div.wrapper .content ul.feeder li.item a {
        padding:10px;
    }
    div.wrapper .content ul.feeder li.item:hover {background:#F7F7F7;}
```

Answer (score -4):

min-height will help you out in this.